# Using a multi-page form to submit data to a sql db

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, tabs, webforms

I currently have a form created using .tabs with jQuery.  This seems to work but is killing my organization.  I have also found an issue that the length of the page is causing issues.  I also have jQuery Show/Hide functionality which may also be causing the page length issue.   Is there a more organized, way of managing a multi-page form and only submitting to the database once?

The current setup:

```
$(function () {
         $("#nav-Container").tabs("#page-Container section", {
             effect: 'fade',
             fadeOutSpeed: 0,
             fadeInSpeed: 400,
         });
     });
```

Comment: Have you tried the MultiView control?

Comment: @pinoy_ISF No I have not.  I'm fairly new to C# and ASP.Net but I did read up on the MultiView Controller a little and it seems to be much more interested than .tabs in jQuery.   The MultiView Control seems to be a great opportunity to implement a Summery page as well.   Any pointers or additional information?    btw, thanks for the MultiView suggestion.